# Login que rediriga a la página actual y no al index | HTTP_REFERER

Tags: php, login, session

Estoy haciendo uso de las sesiones en todas las páginas de mi sitio, es el mismo para todas al comienzo del `body`:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION["usuario"])){

      header("Location:login.php");

    }

   ?>
```

Tengo estas páginas:

login.php

validation.php

index.php

pagina2.php

Si el usuario ingresa directamente a la página2.php sin registrarse, automáticamente se le envía a la página login.php, una vez el usuario ingresa sus credenciales, pasa por el validation.php que lo envía al index.php

Aquí radica mi problema: ¿Cómo logro que el validation.php no me mande al index.php sino a la página actual desde donde se solicitó el login (pagina2.php por ejemplo)?

Ya sé que en mi validador tengo `header("location:index.php");` que me envía a dicha página después del login.

Intenté usar el **HTTP_REFERER** en mi location así `header("location:$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']");` , pero sin éxito, además por lo que leí no es muy recomendable.

Cómo puedo implementarlo correctamente?

Este es mi validation.php

```html
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Validando la sesión</title>
  </head>
  <body>

<?php
try {

$base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=login", "root", "");

$base->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql="SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE USUARIOS= :login AND PASSWORD= :password";

$resultado=$base->prepare($sql);

$login=htmlentities (addslashes($_POST["login"]));

$password=htmlentities (addslashes($_POST["password"]));

$resultado->bindValue(":login", $login);

$resultado->bindValue(":password", $password);

$resultado->execute();

$numero_registro=$resultado->rowCount();

if($numero_registro!=0) {

  session_start ();

  $_SESSION["usuario"]=$_POST["login"];

  header("location:index.php");


} else {
  header("location:login.php");
}



} catch (\Exception $e) {

die ("Error: " . $e->getMessage());


}




     ?>
     
 </body>
</html>
```

PD:
Estoy haciendo pruebas localmente con Wamp
Uso MySQL para la base de datos de los usuarios

**EDITADO**

---

Añado login.php

```html
<html>
<body class="align">

  <div class="grid">

    <div id="login">

      <h2><img src="images/banner-wh.png" alt="Banner" style="max-width: 100%; width: auto;"></h2>

      <form action="validation.php" method="POST">

        <fieldset>

          <p><label for="email">Usuario</label></p>
          <p><input type="text" name="login" id="email"></p>

          <p><label for="password">Contraseña</label></p>
          <p><input type="password" name="password" id="password"></p>

          <br><br>

          <p><input class="with-arrow" type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Ingresar"> <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i> </p>

          <br>

          <h1  style="font-size: 12px;color: #444;">¿Olvidó su contraseña?</h1>
          <h1 style="font-size: 10px;color: #555;">Escríbanos a <a href="mailto:contacto@mail.com?subject=Restablecer%20Contraseña%20-%20">contacto@mail.com</a><h1>

        </fieldset>

      </form>

    </div> <!-- end login -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Conceptualmente puedes hacer algo así: Si accedes a la pagina2.php y no ha iniciado sesión debes redirigirlo a tu página de login, en tu página de login debes setear un campo hidden llamada url con el valor del HTTP_REFERER, después, cuando haces el submit para validar el login: si esta OK puedes preguntar si viene una url válida en la variable _POST['url'] la usas y haces el header("Location: $url") si no, haces el location a tu página por defecto ej. home.php (editado)

Comment: Gracias por responder, cómo puedo usar el location: $url? Puedo lograrlo como un PHP_SELF sobre la misma página?

Comment: se supone que en $_POST['url'] viene definida la página a la cual intentó acceder pero no estaba logueado.. tienes que setearla así: $url = $_POST['url']; y después usarla, no se si me entendiste el flujo.. pagina2 sin logueo redirecciona a login acá se crea el hidden url que será enviado al validation ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trata de hacer lo siguiente:

1) En tu login.php crea el siguiente hidden dentro del formulario: si viene un referer lo usa, de lo contrario deja vacío el valor de url

```php
<form action="validation.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';?>"/>
    ...
</form>
```

2) en tu validation.php agrega lo siguiente:

```php
if($numero_registro!=0) {
    session_start ();

    $_SESSION["usuario"]=$_POST["login"];

    if (isset($_POST['url']) && strlen($_POST['url'])) {
        // redirecciona a la url
        header("location:".$_POST['url']);
    }

    // redirecciona al index x defecto
    header("location:index.php");

} else {
    header("location:login.php");
}
```

Comment: Me presenta el siguiente error en pantalla:  Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER in C:\wamp64\www\intranet\login.php on line 34 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0004236280{main}( )...\login.php:0 ">
Después de ingresar las credenciales, puedo acceder, pero siempre al index

Comment: sube el codigo de tu login.php, verifica que al hidden url se le asigne un valor

Comment: modifiqué el código del hidden.. prueba la modificación

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta con el login.php, gracias por tu paciencia

Comment: agrega el input hidden modificado.. y cuéntame como te va

Answer (score 2):

Una alternativa al *HTTP_REFERER* es usar ***$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']*** (que devuelve la URL que estás ejecutando pero relativa a la raíz de tu dominio) y usar una variable de sesión para guardarla, algo así:

```
$_SESSION['pagina_actual'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

y luego del logueo retornar a la página con

```
header("Location: ". $_SESSION['pagina_actual'])
```

Saludos!,